# Seeking Kaf HaHaim:

Tags: jewish-books, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Once again on a search for a very important book, Kaf HaHaim, that has bad print and not formatted well with sources. Me and my brother wanted to this but kinda gave up. Are they making a new version formatted well?

Comment: Bits and pieces of it are actually already up on Wikitext, [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%A3_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D).

Comment: @Alex thank you very much, but I am looking for in print and with footnotes.

Comment: It is not entirely clear from the question's wording if you're *intentionally seeking* a version with bad print and poor formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your question. As Aryeh points out below, there's more than one book by that title. Could you please tell us the name of the author of the book you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was one called Kaf HaChaim Menukad.  It was a laser-print text, menukad (vocalized), though I don't know about corrections to his actual sources or not (or if they are needed).  However, I believe that only one or two volumes were ever printed, and that now they are out of print.  I still see it on shelves in some Jerusalem stores, but it can no longer be found on web stores.

Answer (score 5):

There's [this notice](http://www.shtaygen.co.il/?CategoryID=1415&ArticleID=5042) from a few years ago about some people planning just such an edition (and asking for corrections to the printed text), though whether it's actually been published yet I don't know. All they give for contact information is a fax number.

Answer (score 4):

## Kaf HaChaim by Rabbi Yaakov Chaim Sofer

There's a new print available, published in 5774 (2014) by Machon HaRisonim v'HaAcharonim. It has improved print quality, many of the printing errors from the original editiosn are fixed, and many of the rashei teivot have been expanded (though it appears that sources who are mostly known by their rashei teivot, like the Taz, have not been expanded). It doesn't have any new footnotes, but the original never needed them, as the author meticulously documented all of his sources right in the text.

Here are several places to buy it:

- [Seforim Center](http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=10046&strReferer=search&PPGR=0) in Brooklyn
- [Otzar Sefarim](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/18158/%D7%9B%D7%A3-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8-10-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%94) in Israel. Their web site shows sample pages from this new edition. Their phone number is 074-703-7171 or 050-6752-752.
- [Zol Sefer](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/171616/%D7%9B%D7%A3-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8-10-%D7%9B%D7%A8) in Israel. Their web site shows sample pages from this new edition. Their phone number is 08-858-0929 or 052-242-4463.
- [Mekor Judaica](https://www.mekorjudaica.com/--Kaf-Hachaim-new.aspx) in Brooklyn

Answer (score 1):

## Kaf HaChaim by Rabbi Chaim Palaggi

A newly typeset version of [R' Chaim Palaggi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haim_Palachi)'s Kaf HaChaim was just uploaded to hebrewbooks.org:
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/53455

It has been completely retypeset, with some introductions added as well. You can compare it to a version published in 1859 [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/7882). (see the note in the new version on the top of the page [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53455&pgnum=457)).

Comment: The link, btw, is for Haim Palaggi's important book of halachot of the same name. Most people, when discussing to Kaf HaHaim, are referring to R. Yakov Haim Sofer's commentary to the Shulchan Arukh.

Comment: @Aryeh, Thanks. I had considered discussing both seforim in my answer above, because it's kinda unclear which sefer the question is taking about. (For example, one wouldn't accuse R' Sefer of omitting sources.)

Comment: @Menachem' As far as I know, that's the whole thing.